# How should the cin.ignore() function be used in this code?

Tags: c++, c++14, testcase

My goal is to solve this:

> Given a string S, of length N that is indexed from 0  to N-1, print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as 2 space-separated strings on a single line

```
int main() {

    int test;
    cin>>test;
    for(int j = 0; j < test; j++){

        char str[10000];
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(str,9999);
        for( int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        {
            if(i % 2 == 0)
                cout<<str[i];
        }
        cout <<" ";
        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        {
            if((i % 2 != 0))
                cout<<str[i];
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The above code gives me output as :

```
Hce akr 
ak n
```

for the given input of:

```
2 
Hacker
Rank
```

But when I use `cin>>str` instead of the `cin.ignore()` and `cin.getline()`, I get the correct expected output: How does that change the result?

```
Hce akr 
Rn ak
```

Comment: Please read more about [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) and what it does. Think about how you use it together with the [`ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) function and what it does.

Comment: My rule of thumb is `ignore` goes AFTER the operation that leaves unwanted characters in the stream. Almost every time you place ignore before another operation you come to regret it.

Comment: My rule of thumb is that, if you have to use `cin.ignore()` at all, then you are reading from `cin` in a very bad way.    Generally speaking, if you mix `cin >> <whatever>` with `cin.getline()`, you will get problems, because they handle some aspects of input (newlines, error conditions) differently, so they interact in unwanted ways.   `cin.ignore()` can paper over those errors but, if you read more input in a mixed manner, that gets tough too. Try reading *everything* from `cin` using `getline()` - and parse the lines as needed - rather than using `cin >> ...` and `cin.getline()` together.

Comment: The problem is underspecified. it is not clear that the strings are to be read from the input in the first place; the task could simply be to provide a *function that gets a string* and prints the two result strings in the specified fashion. Can the string S (note that the assignment does not say "word"!) contain spaces? If not, simply read words from the input with operator>>(string). No need for getline, no need for ignore at all. If yes: We need an end marker. If that is a newline you simply read with getline, but then you need a single ignore after reading the first number.

Comment: By the way: Upvote for (1) Showing a significant own effort with reasonable code, in fact a self-contained minimal example. I would give you three upvotes for that alone, if I could. (2) Stating the desired outcome; (3) Stating the actual outcome. And behold: You get helpful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should Write **cin.ignore();** before **for loop** . Your code ignoring first charecter of every string without first iteration. You need to ignore line break for only test not for every string .

see the below code :

```cpp
int main() {

    int test;
    cin>>test;
    cin.ignore();
    for(int j = 0; j < test; j++){

        char str[10000];
        cin.getline(str,9999);
        //cin>>str;

        for( int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        {
            if(i % 2 == 0)
                cout<<str[i];
        }
        cout <<" ";
        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        {
            if((i % 2 != 0))
                cout<<str[i];
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**input :**
5
Hacker
Rank
WoW
check
lastone

**output :**
Hce akr
Rn ak
WW o
cek hc
lsoe atn

Answer (score 1):

**Using `ignore()`+`getline()`**:

On the first loop iteration, `cin.ignore()` skips the line break that was left behind from `cin>>test`, then `cin.getline()` reads the entire line (`Hacker`) *including but swallowing the line break*.

On the second loop iteration, `cin.ignore()` skips the 1st character of the next line (`R`), and then `cin.getline()` reads the remaining characters of the same line (`ank`) including but swallowing the line break.

The solution is to move the call to `cin.ignore()` to above the loop:

```cpp
cin>>test;
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // <-- move here

for(int j = 0; j < test; j++){
    char str[10000];
    cin.getline(str,9999);
    ...
}
```

**Using `operator>>`**:

On the first loop iteration, `cin>>str` skips the line break that was left behind from `cin>>test` and then reads the next available word (`Hacker`).

On the second loop iteration, `cin>>str` skips the line break that was left behind from the previous `cin>>str` and then reads the next available word (`Rank`).